# Not able to connect with azure knowledgeBase created by language studio and use code given below:-

Tags: node.js, express, botframework

```
const { ActivityTypes } = require("botbuilder");
const { QnAMaker } = require("botbuilder-ai");

// Replace with your own Azure Knowledge Base values
const knowledgeBaseId = "**************************9e72";
const endpointKey = "4981***********************";
const host = "https://botlanguageservice-***.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";

const qnaMaker = new QnAMaker({
    knowledgeBaseId: knowledgeBaseId,
    endpointKey: endpointKey,
    host: host,
});
async function onMessage(context) {
    if (context.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
        const results = await qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);
        if (results.length > 0) {
            await context.sendActivity(results[0].answer);
        }
        else {
            await context.sendActivity(
                "Sorry, I couldn't find an answer to your question."
            );
        }
    }
}

let c = "hey";
onMessage(c);
```

Here is my instance of code that i am using to connect to azure botbuilder. It's returning null in the output may be i am missing some configuration to connect to the bot.

Comment: This is custom QnA and you required a project name instead of a knowledge base id.

Answer (score 1):

Custom QnA is part of Language Studio, So you need to use the Project name instead of Knowledgebase Id.

```
const ProjectName = "name of your project";
const LanguageEndpointKey = "4981***********************";
const LanguageEndpointHostName = "https://botlanguageservice-***.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";

this.qnaMaker = new CustomQuestionAnswering({
            knowledgeBaseId: ProjectName,
            endpointKey: LanguageEndpointKey,
            host: LanguageEndpointHostName
        });
```

You can refer Microsoft document : [Custom QnA code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/12.customQABot/bots/CustomQABot.js)